# How to use rails plugin - fetcher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm making a rails app which should receive e-mails. So I made a little research and figured out that I should use Fetcher plugin. But the problem is that I don't know how to use it!
Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't know how much more clear anyone could be then the readme here http://github.com/look/fetcher

maybe you could be a bit more specific about what problem you are running into.

Comment: When you use
@fetcher = Fetcher.create({:type => :pop,
  :receiver => IncomingMailHandler,
  :server => 'mail.example.com',
  :username => 'jim',
  :password => 'test'})
What should IncomingMailHandler be? What methods should this class implement? And then how can i use the data retrieved from @fetcher.fetch

Comment: I helped write this plugin. IncomingMailHandler is an ActionMailer::Base subclass with a receive method. Read about receiving email with Rails to understand how that works. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#M001562